# How to cast ArrayList<String> to String

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> contentArray = new ArrayList<String>();

for(HashMap<ArrayList<String>, String> subTopicsEntry : subTopics){
    contentArray = (ArrayList<String>) subTopicsEntry.get("Content");
}
```

It gives me error that arraylist cannot be cast to java.lang.string.

What is wrong here?

If i do it like this:

```
ArrayList<?> contentArray = new ArrayList<?>();

for(HashMap<?, ?> subTopicsEntry : subTopics){
    contentArray = (ArrayList<?>) subTopicsEntry.get("Content");
}
```

it works

What is the difference ?

Comment: Your hashmap type seems backwards.

Comment: Sorry i didint get you?

Comment: `Arrays.asList` *doesn't* return an `ArrayList`. Why are you casting to `ArrayList`? And why are you replacing the value of the variable on every iteration? It's entirely unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think the problem is with the key type.

Comment: you can't get("Content") because your hashmap's keys are arraylists<string> so it can't accept a string. if you want to give it a string and get an arraylist, then your hashmap is backwards. it should be HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>...which is what @SLaks was saying.

Comment: @SLaks: I think there's more than one problem, to be honest...

Comment: Can you show how you defined and initialized subTopics ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Arrays.asList()` returns `List<String>`, not `ArrayList<String>`.

You have to define your variable as this:

```
List<String> contentArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But that's not all the problems you have here.

Comment: After your last edit it's totally unclear what you're trying to do. Please post entire piece of code if you want meaningful answers.

Comment: You defined HashMap with keys as array lists and values as strings. I don't think that's what you ultimately wanted to do in your program.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have noted, you have (probably) misdeclared your Map.  Perhaps you mean

```
ArrayList<String> contentArray = new ArrayList<String>(); // this initializer is unnecessary, btw

for(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> subTopicsEntry : subTopics){
  contentArray = subTopicsEntry.get("Content"); // Note that a cast is no longer necessary
}
```

I question whether you really want `ArrayList`s here, but without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to say.

Comment: And as for the second part of the question - the lines that work for you work because you're telling the compiler that `subTopicsEntry` can contain anything, and casting from an `Object` to an `ArrayList<?>` is suspicious but syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

My answer code is:

```
package Examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExampleClass
{
private List<String> _list;

@Override
public String toString() // override default method
{
    String temp = "";
    for (String s : this._list)
    {
        temp += (temp.length() == 0 ? "" : ", ") + s;
    }
    return "ExampleClass: [" + temp + "]";
}

public ExampleClass() // initialize this example class
{
    this._list = new ArrayList<>();
    this._list.add("Hello!");
    this._list.add("Ciao!");
    this._list.add("Good morning!");
    this._list.add("Good afternoon!");
}
}

/*

// some code for using example
ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();
// prints next text to console:
// ExampleClass: [Hello!, Ciao!, Good morning!, Good afternoon!]
System.out.println(ec.toString());

*/
```

Have a nice day. Yuri